# Receiving one UDP packet in C and continue loop

Tags: c, sockets, char, udp

I try to receive one packet via udp.
My problem is, that the loop immediately stops if no data is sent.(I dont leave the loop)

Does my char msg lose its value, if no data is sent?

If somebody knows how to prevent that, I would be really happy if you could share it with me

FYI: The data I receive has the form  i:j (i from 0 to 3, j from 0 to 255. At the moment Im only interested in the part before ":" thats why I cut it)

```
        GetBLCtrlADRExecuteOrder(&BLCtrlADRExecuteOrder[0]);

        int serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        struct sockaddr_in serverAdress;
        serverAdress.sin_family = PF_INET;
        serverAdress.sin_port = htons(4999);
        serverAdress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAdress,
                sizeof(serverAdress));

        while (1) {

            char msg[7];
            struct sockaddr_in client;

            socklen_t adressSize = sizeof(client);
            recvfrom(serverSocket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0,
                    (struct sockaddr*) &client, &adressSize);

            printf("Here is the message: %s\n", msg);

            char *c = strtok(msg, ":");
            printf("toke %s \n", c);

            if (strcmp(c, v0) == 0) {
                pwmValue0 = 10;
                sendBuffer0[0] = pwmValue0;
                g_lldI2c_WriteI2c_bl(BLCtrlADRExecuteOrder[0],
                        &sendBuffer0[0], 1);
            }

            if (strcmp(c, v1) == 0) {

                pwmValue1 = 10;
                sendBuffer1[0] = pwmValue1;
                g_lldI2c_WriteI2c_bl(BLCtrlADRExecuteOrder[1],
                        &sendBuffer1[0], 1);

            }

            if (strcmp(c, v2) == 0) {
                pwmValue2 = 10;
                sendBuffer2[0] = pwmValue2;
                g_lldI2c_WriteI2c_bl(BLCtrlADRExecuteOrder[2],
                        &sendBuffer2[0], 1);

            }

            if (strcmp(c, v3) == 0) {
                pwmValue3 = 10;
                sendBuffer3[0] = pwmValue3;
                g_lldI2c_WriteI2c_bl(BLCtrlADRExecuteOrder[3],
                        &sendBuffer3[0], 1);

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Does the sender include the trailing null character in the message?

Comment: `recvfrom()` waits for a packet. If you don't send a packet, it just stays there, and the loop doesn't end.

Comment: the sended data has its value between 0 and 255 followed by \n

Comment: Since you're using string functions on `msg`, it needs a trailing null.

Comment: yes I thought that too, but if I dont send anything he doesnt print msg nor jumps in one of the cases

Comment: If you don't send anything, `revcfrom()` never returns, unless you make the socket non-blocking.

Comment: Im sorry if im asking stupidly:
If it never returns msg stays empty?

If so: Why does its lose its value after one round?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If it never returns, it never does anything to `msg`. The code that uses `msg` never runs.

Comment: I send my packet one time. Then everything runs fine for one loop
But I want to send it one time and the code below continues indepenently from above

Comment: When you send the one packet, it processes that packet. Then it goes back to the beginning of the loop and waits for the next packet. If you don't send another packet, it will wait there forever.

Comment: aah okay thank you
Is nonblocking the solution?
Or is there a nicer way to solve this?

Comment: The solution is probably to put something in the packet that indicates that it's the last packet, so that you can break out of the loop instead of waiting for another packet. Or if there's only one packet expected, don't use a loop.

Comment: Making it non-blocking won't help, you still need to know when to break out of the loop.

Comment: aaah now I got it
Thank you very much
Have a nice day =)

Comment: Your problem is the loop stops imediately. Define "stops"?